# HTTP requests to Github Database API via Python keep returning 404

Tags: python, json, http, github, python-requests

I've recently been experimenting with the GitHub API. Currently I am trying to access data (particularly tags) from the Git database for one of my repositories but later on I'd like to be able to create new tag objects once I get a better feel for things. What I mean by the GitHub database API is this: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git

I've been trying to use the the http GET requests for Git tags (as specified in the documentation pointed to in the above link) in the following code (specifically the code blocks labelled #3 and #4):

```
import requests
import time
from requests import api

github_username = "XXXXX"
github_accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
github_repoName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


print(end="\n\n\n")

# 1
# Getting basic user information
print("Getting basic user Information:")
gitHubAPI_URL_getUserInfo = f"https://api.github.com/users/{github_username}"
response = requests.get(gitHubAPI_URL_getUserInfo, auth=(github_username, github_accessToken))
data = response.json()
print("MetaData:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print(response)
print(type(data))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Data:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for key, value in data.items():
    print(str(key) + ": " + str(value))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print()
print("====================================================================")
print()


# 2
# Getting tags
print("Getting tags:")
gitHubAPI_URL_getTags = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{github_username}/{github_repoName}/tags"
response = requests.get(gitHubAPI_URL_getTags, auth=(github_username, github_accessToken))
data = response.json()
print("MetaData:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print(response)
print(type(data))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Data:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for element in data:
    print("///////")
    for key, value in element.items():
        print(str(key) + ": " + str(value))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print()


# 3
# Getting tags alternate attempt 1
print("Getting a particualr tag attempt 1 (Auth):")
gitHubAPI_URL_getTags_particular1 = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{github_username}/{github_repoName}/git/tags"
response = requests.get(gitHubAPI_URL_getTags_particular1, auth=(github_username, github_accessToken))
data = response.json()
print("MetaData:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print(response)
print(type(data))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Data:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for key, value in data.items():
    print(str(key) + ": " + str(value))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print()
print("====================================================================")
print()


# 4 
# Getting tags alternate attempt 2
print("Getting a particualr tag attempt 2 (Headers):")
gitHubAPI_URL_getTags_particular2 = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{github_username}/{github_repoName}/git/tags/"
header = {"Authorization" : 'token ' + github_accessToken}
response = requests.get(gitHubAPI_URL_getTags_particular2, headers=header)
data = response.json()
print("MetaData:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print(response)
print(type(data))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Data:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for key, value in data.items():
    print(str(key) + ": " + str(value))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print()
print("====================================================================")
print()


# 5
# Getting commits
print("Getting commits:")
gitHubAPI_URL_getCommits = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{github_username}/{github_repoName}/commits"
response = requests.get(gitHubAPI_URL_getCommits, auth=(github_username, github_accessToken))
data = response.json()
print("MetaData:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print(response)
print(type(data))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("Data:")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for element in data:
    print("///////")
    for key, value in element.items():
        print(str(key) + ": " + str(value))
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

However for these code blocks I keep getting 404 - "Resource not found" error codes back from GitHub. Initially I thought this was an authentication issue as I was not providing authentication credentials at first and 404 error codes are what GitHub's REST API returns without proper authentication: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/troubleshooting.

But even after adding proper authorization I'm still getting 404's returned. I am confident I have filled out the authentication correctly since whenever I change any of the credential variables (such as the value of 'github_accessToken') to some invalid value (like changing a character in the personal access token value) I get 401 - "Bad Credentials" returned on code blocks #1, #2, and #5 which would work fine before.

The only conclusion I can come to is that there is genuinely no data from where I am requesting data from but this makes no sense to me as I know the repository and the data I am requesting exists, unless I am misunderstanding things and there is a difference between a GitHub database and a GitHub Repository

Comment: What scopes does the token you're using have?

Comment: full scope - admin:enterprise, admin:gpg_key, admin:org, admin:org_hook, admin:public_key, admin:repo_hook, delete:packages, delete_repo, gist, notifications, repo, user, workflow, write:discussion, write:packages

Comment: What type of token? If it is a **Personal Access Token** then use the HTTP header **Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN** instead of username/password basic authorization.

Comment: Thanks John Hanley, will try that, I can confirm that it is a personal access token

Answer (score 0):

I am able to replicate your issue and I am pretty sure your authentication in code block #2 is correct and getting the `404` is not due to the authentication.

According to [GitHub API Docs about Tags](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#tags), you can only

1. **Create a tag object**

   - Do a `POST` on `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/tags` with some parameters
2. **Get a tag**

   - Do a `GET` on `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/tags/{tag_sha}`

What you did was neither of the two operation. I believe you are trying to do the second operation of getting a tag, in which case your request is wrong, since you did not provide a `TAG_SHA` at the end of your `GET` request's URL.

Comment: Do you have to provide a specific tag_sha? I know that for code block #2 I can also specify a specific tag_sha but I don't in this case and GitHub's REST API provides me with a list of tags absent of any specification. I sort of assumed the same would work for code blocks #3 and #4

Comment: No, the `tag_sha` is not optional and you need to provided as stated in the **Official GitHub API Documentation**. I recommend following the documentation.